# automaticaaly do refresh token if its expired

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I have this code

```
    <cfscript>
    public struct function CreateToken() {
          var result = '';
          var apiKeys = {
            'appKey' : variables.username,
            'appSecret': variables.password
          };
          httpService = new http(method = "POST", url = "https://wesa.com/v1/tokens/create");
          httpService.addParam(type = "header", name="Content-Type", value = "application/json");
          httpService.addParam(type = "body", value = "#parseBody(apiKeys)#");
          result = httpService.send().getprefix();
          if(result.statuscode == '200') {
            resultDeserialized = deserializeJSON(result.fileContent);
          }
          return resultDeserialized;
        }
    
        public struct function RefreshToken(required string token) {
          var apiStruct = [:];
          apiStruct['refreshToken'] = arguments.token;
          httpService = new http(method = "POST", url = "https://wesa.com/v1/tokens/refresh");
          httpService.addParam(type = "header", name="Content-Type", value = "application/json");
          httpService.addParam(type = "body", value = "#parseBody(apiStruct)#");
          result = httpService.send().getprefix();
          if(result.statuscode == '200') {
            resultDeserialized = deserializeJSON(result.fileContent);
          }
          return resultDeserialized;
        }
    
    </cfscript>
```

But I am trying to understand how do I automatically call the refresh token because if the token is active and expired, it gives me a 401 status.

I am not getting the underlying behaviour how can I automatically use to refresh it and then call the API for calls.

It's like the same, the expires is 8900 seconds, so not sure even the refresh token will be available after the time expired or check if its getting expired, just call refresh token

I just need some kind of direction on how can I use it

Answer (score 2):

you can build an interceptor that refreshes token when response status is 401.

I have done in react js like this

```
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    return response
}, error => {
    const originalRequest = error.config;

    if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
        originalRequest._retry = true;
        const refreshToken: string = localStorage.getItem('refreshToken') || '';
        const user: string = localStorage.getItem('user') || '';
        let email: string;
        if (refreshToken.length === 0 && user.length === 0) {
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }
        email = JSON.parse(user).email;
        return axiosInstance.post(refreshTokenUrl,
            {
                "email": `${email}`,
                "refreshToken": `${refreshToken}`
            }).then(res => {
            if (res.status === 200) {
                localStorage.setItem('token', res.data.token)
                const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("token");
                originalRequest.headers.authorization = 'Bearer ' + accessToken;
                return axios(originalRequest)
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Or you can set timer that refreshes just before token expires

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not using react, but the way I am calling my API, is: new myAPI.Senddata(form) -- now send send internally calls the CreateToken and sets the header Authorization and if the token is expired, it should refresh and append that token to the heazder so the call can be made successfully

Comment: Sorry I can't help there. I only know React. I was just trying to say u can use Interceptor for refreshing token.